# Switch statement with Multiple conditions

Tags: c#

I am writing a C# web-testing project for an application that will read a value from an XML config file and perform automated testing. The code I have right now is working, however, it has to be changed every time the requirements are updated.

```
private void takeAction(string keyData, string locator, string action)
{
    switch (keyData)
    {
        case "Origin":
            if (action == "Input")
            {
                origin_input(locator, "MEL");
            }

            break;

        case "Destination":
            if (action == "Input")
            {
                destination_input(locator, "Manila");
            }
            break;

        case "DepartDate":
            if (action == "Input")
            {
                textinput(locator, "21/10/2014");
            }
            break;

        case "ReturnDate":
            if (action == "Input")
            {
                textinput(locator, "06/11/2014");
            }
            break;

        case "Adult":
            if (action == "Select")
            {
                objSelect(locator, "3");
            }
            break;

        case "SearchButton":
            if (action == "Button")
            {
                objClick(locator);
            }
            break;

           ...
    }
}
```

This code matches the name of the object, checks the required action, and then calls the appropriate function with a few parameters.

I have read some examples of the Open/Closed Principle, however, I could not solve this issue as there are multiple conditions being checked at same time.

As more "keydata" will be added into the code, I believe the switch statement does not seem to be the correct option here. Any advice on improving this code would be appreciated.

Comment: Depends on how your other code is organized.try using Dictionary (map)

Comment: possibly you need [T4 template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx), that generate this switch automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could declaratively define your cases as shown below. You could also use classes, but that gets more complicated because the classes need access to the methods that you're passing `locator` into. If this approach still calls for more separation, then it might be worth making each case into a class.

#### Interface

```
public delegate void TestAction(string locator);

public class ActionCase
{
    public string ExpectedAction { get; set; }
    public TestAction Test { get; set; }
}
```

#### Definitions

```
private Dictionary<string, ActionCase> cases = new Dictionary<string, ActionCase>
{
    {
        "Origin",
        new ActionCase
        {
            ExpectedAction = "Input",
            Test = locator => origin_input(locator, "MEL")
        }
    },
    //Define the rest here
};
```

#### Usage

```
private void takeAction(string keyData, string locator, string action)
{
    var case = cases[keyData];
    if (action == case.ExpectedAction)
        case.Test(locator);
}
```

Comment: I would give this a try. Since u have created Action class as an interface ,  why it is not been used in Definitions?

Comment: @Billyuatbcs, sorry; it was meant to be defined as `ActionCase`. I just updated the answer to correct this.

Comment: There is an error from "Test = locator => origin_input" showing A field initializer can not reference non-static method , do i have to change all methods to static?

Comment: @Billyuatbcs, that implies `origin_input` is a non-static method. It's hard to give you advice about that without knowing the bigger picture of the code you're working with. You could ask a separate question if you want ideas about how to do that.

Comment: @Billyuatbcs, but yes; changing the methods to static is one option, although I don't know if it will be possible. Another option is assigning to the field in the class constructor. Another option is storing the data in a property or local variable instead of a field.

Answer (score 3):

IF I were you I'd use some sort of abstraction. For instance all methods you call inside the individual if statements within the switch take string `locator` and an optional other string parameter (or none in the last case). Furthermore I think you can simplify the logic by combining the value of the `keyData` and the `acton` parameters since when combined they produce unique key.

What you can do with this is the following:

```
public interface ITestableAction{
    void Execute(string locator);
}

public class OriginInputAction : ITestableAction{
    public void Execute(string locator){
        origin_input(locator, "MEL");  //I'd make the origin_input method static...
    }
}

public class DestinationInputAction : ITestableAction{
    public void Execute(string locator){
        destination_input(locator, "Manila");    
    }
}
```

finally your class needs to have a dictionary where the `keyData` and the `acton` will represent the keys.

```
private Dictionary<string, ITestableAction> actions = 
    new Dictionary<string, ITestableAction>();

actions.Add("OriginInput", new OriginInputAction());
actions.Add("DestinationInput", new DestinationInputAction());
```

etc...

so in your method instead of constantly having to check the different ways you can pair all `keyData` and `action` values you simply look up the corresponding ITestableAction for their sum:

```
private void takeAction(string keyData, string locator, string action)
{
   string key = string.Format("{0}{1}", keyData, action);

   if(actions.ContainsKey(key))
   {
      ITestableAction action = actions[key]
      action.Execute(locator);
   }    
}
```

This is one of the "I am supposed to know it" design patterns. Can't really put my finger on what exactly it is, but it's useful. It's supposed to help you because you don't have change the logic so much every time. Just create a new class that inherits from ITestableAction and add it to the dictionary. At the end of the day the logic tree becomes shorter. But then again, please don't take this at face value... there are hundreds of ways to code something, and only you know your requirements and stakes. This is just a suggestion to hopefully point you in the right direction.

Thanks,

Martin.

Comment: A trade-off of this approach is that when you add an action, you have to add code to **two** locations rather than just one: the dictionary and adding a new class.

Comment: To address the above trade-off, I suggest that the interface define a property to determine the key. Then you could just build the dictionary from the `IEnumerable<ITestableAction>`.

Comment: you do realize we are talking about the same thing... you are just using a lambda right?!?

Comment: I considered it, and yes yours is cleaner. But either way you still have to build the dictionary of "cases"

Comment: Yeah; I do realise that, but I'm not sure what your point is.

Comment: Regarding adding the key to the interface, you're right; it doesn't really make much difference since you still have the `locator`-dependent logic split away from the rest of the "case".

Comment: I got what you mean here Martin, using abstract methods should be practical approach. But as Sam has mentioned , the "action" and "keydata" will be added in the future as this is developed for a web-testing.

Comment: Also, concatenating the two keys (`keyData` and `action`) depends on the assumption that the results will still be unique and not ambiguous.

Comment: By the way, I suspect that a plain string concatenation `keyData + action` will be more performant than `String.Format` since the latter needs to parse the format string.

Comment: @bleepzter I think the name of the pattern you are referring to is the Strategy Pattern that then uses an Abstract Factory to build the dictionary of strategies.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could simply do something like:

```
switch (keyData + action)
{
    case "OriginInput":
        origin_input(locator, "MEL");
        break;
}
```

Comment: The combination of strings could get rid of that if statement , this may help a bit

Answer (score -1):

I think you just need an extra variable

```
private void takeAction(string keyData, string locator, string action, string searchfor)
        {
            switch (keyData)
            {
                case "Origin":
                    if (action == "Input")
                    {
                        origin_input(locator, searchfor);
                    }

                    break;
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I got your idea but what I am looking for is solution for more "keydata" added into this loop , which could make this switch case list super long

Comment: Why not have a variable for that too then? Also if all keys that are the same have the same locator function add a switch for the key name to determine the locator function before the main switch.

Comment: This just moves logic from one place to the other; it doesn't consolidate duplicate logic, and it doesn't necessarily separate the required concerns. The search expressions might intentionally be kept near the rest of the stuff in the `case`s.